# How to switch between GNU Terminal windows with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, gnu

I m using Ubuntu 16.x version, Just wondering if there is a short-cut to switch ONLY between different terminal(GNU) that I use ?

Comment: What's a "GNU Terminal"? Did you perhaps mean "GNOME Terminal" instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to switch between different windows of the same application, including the terminal.

Comment: But it also shows other applications (in small size though). Just wondering if we can use a command that can only show ONLY the list terminal windows.